# How to find an item [array] in a dart list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list with with an array of Objects added with this code:

```dart
_selectedItems.add([color, size, type]);
```

Each time I update the quantity of an item I have to call a method to verify if the list already have that item (if yes, update the quantity. if not, add the item and the quantity). So I tried this code:

```dart
print(_selectedItems.contains([color, size, type])); // searching if this product is in the list
```

But it always return false. I tried too verify the id's of each Object, but it returns false too. What I have to do to be able to reach the goal?

Comment: How about using an object called `Item` instead, and having an id attribute on it? will also make more sense calling `item.color`, `item.size` etc, instead of `item[0]`, `item[1]`...

Comment: In that case you can also make it a `Set` instead, editing the `hashCode` of `Item` class to be the `id` property, and having another property `quantity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .indexWhere() to find an object in a list and return the index:

```
Item _objectToInsert = Item();

int index = _selectedItems.indexWhere((item) => item.color.contains(_objectToInsert.color));
```

If index is -1, the object isn't in the list, else index will be the position of the obect in the list. So you can do:

```
if (index == -1) // add
    _selectedItems.add(_objectToInsert);
else // update
   _objectToInsert[index].color = _objectToInsert.color;
```